# How to get linux terminal print info and save it to a file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How to get linux terminal print info and save it to a file? there are print information about the application, there are kernel print information.I want to save all the terminal program's output to a file, rather than just one application.

Comment: What Linux are you running? and Do you want it saved to a .txt file then printed?

Comment: ubuntu,yes,save it to a .txt.

Comment: What kind of info do you want to save? I cannot understand... what do you mean by `linux terminal print info`?  Do you want a list of printers?  A print queue? Or info about your terminal?

Comment: I want to save all the terminal program's output to a file, rather than just one application.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the standard output of the program and at the same time write it to a file, pipe it to a [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) command:

```
echo "command output" | tee file.txt
```

Replace `echo "command output"` with the command you run.

Comment: I want to save all the terminal program's output to a file, rather than just one application.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @techraf's answer, You can also use this-

```
shell# "your command" >> file.txt
```

This will make a file named file.txt and store the output of the command in the file. **But you won't be able to see the output live on the terminal.**

For example-

```
shell#  ls >> file.txt
```

will store the output of ls command in the file.

Comment: I want to save all the terminal program's output to a file, rather than just one application.

Comment: @Lyric, that doesn't make sense beside, every program that runs on terminal have different and specific requirements. for eg. with grep you have to specify a pattern with lots of different options.

Comment: Please describe you specific requirements clearly.